# ViewDoesNotExist error on linux but same code works on windows, why?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm currently trying to learn django and I've been messing around with an idea for a website on my local machines. I've run into the following error which I don't seem to be able to solve.

When I run the development server on my windows machine everything works as I expect it to, however, when I run the (same) code on my linux machine I get a ViewDoesNotExist error. However the view definitely exists in the views.py file and the path is definitely set up correctly (as I can see from the traceback).

I've read that for some reason django sometimes provides these error messages when in actual fact it has a problem with something else, maybe something imported by the views.py file so I ran

`python manange.py shell`

and tried to import my views, which failed. But my views.py file doesn't import anything other than my models from my models.py file so I tried to import them manually and I found that only one of the models would import properly and the other two would always fail, for example when trying to run:

`from racing.models import Event`

I get the following error

`ImportError: cannot import name Event`

However, when I run:

`from racing.models import Race`

It works fine and I can work with the Race class in the shell

It is as if it can't even see them? All the code can be found here:
https://github.com/sj175/ulmk

If anyone could help me figure out how to solve this error so that I can continue using django on my linux machine I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using djangos `manage.py startproject` should create directory like:

```
cms/
    manage.py
    cms/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

It looks like this is the case with `cms`.  But it looks like your `apps` are a directory higher then they should be:

```
cms/
    manage.py
    cms/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
coltrane/
racing/
tagging/
```

when by default i believe those apps should be inside the `cms` directory, ie inside your django project

```
cms/
    manage.py
    cms/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    coltrane/
    racing/
    tagging/
```

So i'm guessing that your apps are on your pythonpath in windows, and on linux, they are not

Comment: You're right my directory structure is weird. However this is definitely not a path problem as I can import the Race class from racing.models just not the Event or Participant class.

Comment: @SamJones I did a clean checkout of your repository, and moved the apps into the `cms` directory,  After doing that everything is importing fine, i am on ubuntu 11.10

Comment: You're right, I tried changing the directory structure and now it works. I'm sorry I didn't listen before. I have upvoted both answers and selected this one as it was slightly more explicit in describing the fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your folder structure. your manage.py resides inside **cms**, whereas **racing** is outside **cms**

Do go through the documentation 
[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: As above, you're right my directory structure is weird but I don't see how this could be causing the problem.

Comment: that is how django works.
if you check your **manage.py** file 

    `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cms.settings")`

The [os.environ documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) does state **os.environ.setdefault** does mapping.
**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** defines which settings you are using, here you are using **cms.settings**. And **racing** is beyond the reach of it.
If you are learing the basics just go through the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: So how come I could access one of the classes in racing and not the other two? Shouldn't I have not been able to access any of them?

Comment: i just pulled your code form github. and on running  `python manage.py shell`

this error is generated 
**ImportError: No module named racing**

This one is pretty much self-explanatory.

Now did you made recent changes to your code? if so, then push

Comment: I didn't ever get that error message. I didn't make any changes from the master either. 

I find it extremely odd that of three classes in the same file some could be imported but not others and this was a problem with the directory structure. I don't understand how python knew where one of the classes was but not the other two when all three were in the same file.